# Display instruction String (Text) in JComboBox when selection is null

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox<SelectionOption>` where the user can choose from a few options.
By default, none is selected `comboBox.getModel.setSelectedItem(null)`, but I'd like to display a text that says something like "Please choose from the 5 Options" when the selection is null.

Can I achieve this somehow without adding a fake `SelectionOption`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665688/display-a-non-selectable-default-value-for-jcombobox You're looking for a "placeholder". Yes it is entirely doable, just look around at examples.

Comment: Your link looks like something I could use. Thanks very much!