# What text to put to a JComboBox where you want to prompt the user to selection?

Tags: java, swing, label, jcombobox

I am using multiple `JComboBox` in a single `JPanel`. I was wondering what is the go to initial `JComboBox` selection text?

For example I can put "None" but that will seem as if some value is already selected in the `JComboBox`. I am using labels for which type of data they are so writing their type is unnecessary.

I can either put "" but something like "----" seems better. Is there a standard text when you want the user to select some value from `JComboBox`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is very recommended that you have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, it would be much appreciated if you could use a picture to illustrate the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set an initial value to `JComboBox` that should be non-selectable (as soon as user selects another option, it will not be possible to select the initial one again), than it has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665688/display-a-non-selectable-default-value-for-jcombobox?lq=1).

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to me but my main question was rather "What to type in initial `JComboBox` that just feels better for data prompt?". Most likelyI am to obsessive about little things though.. but it seemed like a good question for designers.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a custom renderer. The renderer will simply display a default prompt when no item of the combo box has been selected.

Check out [Combo Box Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/combo-box-prompt/) for an example of this approach.