# Custom JComboBox hiding JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, custom-component, jpopupmenu

I'm having a little headache with a situation. Maybe some of you have been through this before and can show me another way or even my error here.

I need to add a JTree inside a JComboBox and the code below works like a charm.

```
public class HierarchyComboBox extends JComboBox {
    HierarchyTree ht = new HierarchyTree();
    HierarchyComboBox box;
    JPopupMenu popup;
    MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() { 
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getClickCount() == 1) {
                removeAllItems();
                addItem(ht.getSelectedLevel());
//              ((JPopupMenu) comp).setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    };


    PopupMenuListener listener = new PopupMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            if (box == null) {
                box = (HierarchyComboBox) e.getSource();
                if (popup == null) {
                    final Object comp = box.getUI().getAccessibleChild(box, 0);
                    if (!(comp instanceof JPopupMenu))
                        return;
                    popup = (JPopupMenu) comp;
                }
                popup.removeAll();
                ht.getTreePane().setBorder(null);
                ht.getTreePane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(box.getWidth(), 200));
                MyTree tree = (MyTree)ht.getTreePane().getViewport().getComponent(0);
                tree.addMouseListener(adapter);
                popup.add(ht.getTreePane());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent arg0) { }
    };

    public HierarchyComboBox() {
        setEditable(true);
        addPopupMenuListener(listener);
    }
}
```

but I added this component to 2 different dialogs. 
The first one I can click and the selection is added to the JComboBox

and the second, doing EXACTLY the same instantiation, and the same tests
The component has a different behaviour:
 - The JPopupMenu disappears
 - It doesn't add the selection to the combo

Any ideas here?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [*Providing a Custom Renderer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), "A combo box uses a renderer to display each item in its menu." You *could* render the tree in a custom `ListCellRenderer`. Alternatively,

- Render the tree in an adjacent component in response to an `ActionListener`.
- Use a hierarchical model, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231915/230513).

Comment: In this case, it would render the entire tree in one option. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer your popup approach as the other component.

Comment: Exactly. I solved the problem. But thanks for the answer, @trashgod

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the JPopupMenu was loosing it's focus.

The solution was to add the component as the last component of the Panel.

Comment: Yes, I can, but not now. It tells me to wait 2 days.
You can accept your own answer in 2 days