# $nbsp is Replace by some Strange char in Java

Tags: java, swing, replace, character-encoding

I have one Desktop application and I am trying to Run it with Windows Desktop and while its running correct into Ubuntu.

but while running on windows $nbsp is Replaced with some wired Char. "Â" dont know how to make it fix?

any body can give suggestion?[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject data = table.getJSONObject(i);
                 GetStringfromjson.addItem(data.getString("SubActivityName"));
                 getbytesfromjson.addItem(data.getString("SubActivityName").getBytes());
                 gettochararray.addItem(data.getString("SubActivityName").toCharArray());
                 getstringonly.addItem((data.get("SubActivityName").toString().replaceAll("&Acirc;", " ")));
                 //System.out.println(data.get("SubActivityName").toString().trim());
                // System.out.println("*********"+System.getProperty("os.name"));
                 if (System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("Linux")>=0) {

                    System.out.println(data.get("SubActivityName").toString());
                }
                 if (System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("win")>=0) {

                    System.out.println(data.get("SubActivityName").toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates the issue? As usual, a [SCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) is preferred.

Comment: I am just adding item into the combobox and again there is not any issue code its working fine with ubunu but not with wndows still let me show u that code.

Comment: Character-set issue. You need to specify encodings on your string literals and readers.

Comment: @chrylis i know that i have to specify encoding but which encoding will give me result what i need? i know its encoding that is not what i asked.

Comment: Show us how you load the JSON. You broke the data way before the code you posted here.

Comment: one webservice is called and after that response of xml is getting converted to json @KarolS

Comment: That says nothing. Post some code.

Answer (score 2):

Using spaces for formatting in this way is problematic due to platform variations in font metrics and character encoding. Instead, use a custom [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), where you have more control over rendering. A related approach is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5231517/230513).

Comment: then how can i make it fix and mind well m not using any ListCellRenderer for the same.

Comment: I'd recommend changing to a custom `ListCellRenderer` to get the indentation effect shown in your illustration.

Comment: i have not used ListCellRenderer i told u once. and if u still say that then show me demo code i try according to that.

Comment: I cited two examples above. Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your revised approach. See also [*How do I create screenshots?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Comment: how can i make it better? i have uploaded Code which adding items into the Combobox and even screenshots what i am getting output. what more should i post in that?